# How to set custom default size for new XFCE terminal windows?

Tags: xfce

I use XFCE 4.8. I'd like new terminal windows to be wider by default (when I start a new terminal instance), but can't find where to configure this. Do you happen to know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open `~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc` (in older versions `~/.config/Terminal/terminalrc`)
and change the line with `MiscDefaultGeometry` to e.g.
`MiscDefaultGeometry=X*Y*Z` with your default size.

Comment: This is not working at xfce 4.10. New terminals totally ignores this setting

Answer (score 7):

The man page for `xfce4-terminal` specifies using the `--geometry` option to set the size and placement of a terminal.

This flag uses the options  *"**-geometry WIDTHxHEIGHT+XOFF+YOFF** (where WIDTH, HEIGHT, XOFF, and YOFF are numbers) for specifying a preferred size and location for this application's main window."*

Refer to the "Geometry Specifications" section of the man page for X (`man X`).

Here are several examples of xterm placement:

1. Place a short and wide terminal window on upper left-hand side of the display:

   `xfce4-terminal --geometry 140x20+50+50`
2. Place a square terminal window in the lower left-hand corner of the display:

   `xfce4-terminal --geometry 100x40+40+500`
3. Place a square terminal window in the upper right-hand corner of the display:

   `xfce4-terminal --geometry 100x40+1500+40`
4. Place a short and wide terminal window on lower right-hand side of the display:

   `xfce4-terminal --geometry 140x20+1500+500`

How to make this setting permanent:

*"copy the terminal launcher (terminal's .desktop file) from `/usr/share/applications/` to `~/.local/share/applications/` and edit the Exec field accordingly"* as mentioned in the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48984/how-can-i-set-the-position-that-terminal-opens-at).

Comment: The last paragraph is confusing. I'm not sure what the terminals .desktop file is named. And if i need to reboot. There are also multiple answers in that reference. And it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

@palmic is correct, in xfce 4.10 the `~/.config/Terminal/terminalrc` is ignored. Instead, configure `.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc`. It has the same syntax.

More information in docs for `xfce4-terminal(1)` in `ENVIRONMENT` section.

Answer (score 1):

The default geometry can be set in the menu:
Preferences > Appearance : Opening New Window : Default Geometry columns/ rows

Answer (score 1):

Right click the terminal Icon on the panel and choose Properties. In dialog windows that opens choose the edit icon (bottom icon which looks like a pencil with three dots). Another dialog box will open choose Command box and change from lxterminal to

lxterminal --geometry=95x20

or what ever size columns and rows you like

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 14.04 setting the options via "preferences" window didn't work for me.

Window height is not honored.

Editing the config file did work.

Config file location.
`~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc`