# How can I set the position that terminal opens at?

Tags: x11, terminal-emulator, cinnamon, window-management

I'd like Terminal to open near the bottom of my screen.  Is there a way to set the default size and position?

I'm using Linux Mint 13, Cinnamon.

Comment: The answer will vary greatly on what desktop environment (GNOME, KDE etc.) or to be exact, what window manager, you are using.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Most terminals can be launched using the `geometry` switch allowing you to specify terminal's size and position (COLUMNSxROWS+X+Y) e.g.:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry 73x31+100+300
```

or

```
xterm -geometry 93x31+100+350
```

If you want to make the above permanent, copy the terminal launcher (terminal's .desktop file) from `/usr/share/applications/` to `~/.local/share/applications/` and edit the `Exec` field accordingly.

E.g. for gnome-terminal

```
Exec=gnome-terminal --geometry 73x31+100+300
```

Having that custom launcher in your $HOME would preserve your settings after terminal-package upgrades (that would otherwise overwrite the default .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications`).

Comment: I am using `lxterminal` from Lubuntu 11.10 and the help says that I can use the option `geometry=colsxrows` but nothing about the position. Do you know how to fix its position in Lubuntu?

Comment: @Sigur - you could try using [devilspie](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie) to specify the position. Create a file `~/.devilpie/lxterminal.ds` with this content (replace _X_ and _Y_ as per your taste): `(if (is (application_name) "lxterminal") (begin (geometry "+200+350") ) )` save, run `devilspie`  then launch `lxterminal` with desired size: `lxterminal --geometry=COLxROW`. It should be automatically positioned where you want. It works OK in Gnome 3 at least.

Answer (score 13):

## xterm Options Using Xresources or Xdefaults

---

This is the general "syntax" for options that go into the `~/.Xresources` or `~/.Xdefaults` file:

**XTerm*geometry: COLUMNSxROWS+X+Y**

For example

```
XTerm*geometry: 90x30+0+540
```

**Note:**  The first two options (COLUMNSxROWS) depend on your font type/size.

Furthermore, it also depends on the resolution of your Display, as the last two options are for the position of the window; this is calculated in different units than the Window Size of the xterm window.

*When X = 0 then the position is all the way on the left

When Y = 0 then the position is all the way at the top*

If your resolution is e.g. *1920x1080*, then you'd put the **Y** value as **540** (half-way down from the top edge of your display); as the **30 ROWS** value is roughly half the display height on the same-sized display using my own system's fonts, settings.

- [Xresources ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_resources)

Comment: In order to activate the changes I had to run `xrdb .Xdefaults`.

Comment: The example is incorrect.  The XTerm FAQ explains [why](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#tiny_menus)

Answer (score 7):

As an update, the top answer didn't work for me in Ubuntu 18.04 as of Aug. 2018. What got the job done is Hardware -> Keyboard -> Add new command (By hitting plus sign). Fill in the "Command" field with command like `gnome-terminal --geometry 80x55-500+0`. Set the hotkey as Crtl + Alt + T. Done.

Even better, you can add the command to "Startup Applications" to launch the terminal at startup.

Comment: Use this people! (simple effective) (Works well on Ubuntu 19.10)

Comment: Genius!! Works on 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the font size, in lxterminal you could set the default font to the size you want, although this would apply to all terminals. If you were using gnome-terminal you could set up a profile with the desired font size and pass it in using the flag --window-with-profile, but I don't see any related options in lxterminal.

If you don't want this to be your default font size, one potential option is to write a script to modify the config file (by default ~/.config/lxterminal/lxterminal.conf) to change the font size, then launch the program, then revert the font size in the config file. I haven't tested this though.

Answer (score 0):

for me, at this date (*running Mint 21.3 in xfce4 environment*), copying the terminal.desktop file at `~/.local/share/applications/` and editing its `Exec` field, would result nothing.
But I found a solution via this [french forum](https://forum-francophone-linuxmint.fr/viewtopic.php?p=168287#p168287) by editing the `MiscDefaultGeometry` field from `~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc` file