# MATE mate-terminal configuration: raising window at AxB+x+y failing

Tags: mate-desktop, mate-terminal

`MATE Terminal 1.27.1 on 6.6.1-arch1-1`

I want to open my mate-terminal at 300,400. From the command line I can enter `mate-terminal --geometry 80x24+300+200` and get the effect I'm looking for.

I want to make this 'permanent', to have the terminal raise in that position no matter how I raise it.

I found a couple of references :

[How can I set the position that terminal opens at?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48984/how-can-i-set-the-position-that-terminal-opens-at)

`mate-terminal` is a fork of `gnome-terminal` so I hoped that this would help

I copied `/usr/share/applications/mate-terminal.desktop` to `./local/share/applications` and set this line

```
 Exec=mate-terminal --geometry=80x24+300+200
```

Trying `geometry=` and `geometry`  without the `=`. This had no effect.

I tried changing this line :

```
 TryExec=mate-terminal --geometry=80x24+300+200
```

There is **this** from the `Mint forum` which suggests editing the desktop file in `/usr/share/applications` using `mate-desktop-item-edit`, a GUI dialog that offers the exec line as a field.

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=183043

But that doesn't work either.

Any ideas?